# Is this a MySQL injection or what?

Tags: mysql

I get this query in MySQL Worknbench -> Administration  -> Client connection

Running as localhost, so I guess is from the web page.

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
```

It seems like a MySQL injection to me.
If I'm right How I can stop that?

Comment: Do you use JDBC?

http://www.jroller.com/mmatthews/entry/creating_jdbc_connections_doesn_t

Comment: Yes, and NET driver on remote machines too.

Comment: doesn't that answer it then?  injection would do something like add a terminator in the select statement and 'inject' a drop schema or drop table.

Answer (score 0):

Why should this be an SQL injection? All it does is to ask for the state of some runtime variables of the MySQL server and looks a lot like something that MySQL Workbench itself would do to do its work.

Comment: I see a couple of that at same time and I'm running Workbench from a remote PC, so Why that querys are running as localhost?. Plus another query is SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `Alarms`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is actually performing an SQL injection attack through your website, they would probably go after your data and not runtime variables. If you have any suspicion that the query is being run from your webserver, you can check the server access logs for signs of an attack. Even in your MySQL logs, you can look for Select and UNION queries against *your database* that you don't recognize. The queries you have listed look normal, nothing suspicious about them.

Comment: What's the purpose of /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ *  in a query? I'm not familiar whit that. Is an internal process of MySQL server?

Comment: I am not sure what the query is, but there is a lot of reference available for it on the internet.

Comment: yes I know, but I don't know how to search about /* they are ignored on Google Search. I will try with SQL_NO_CACHE

Comment: `SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ ...` is almost certainly either you or someone else making a backup of your data.  Statements enclosed in `/*!mnnrr ... */` are treated as comments (and ignored) by versions of MySQL Server earlier than m.nn.rr (e.g. 4.00.01 here) for backwards compatibility with versions before the feature (e.g. `SQL_NO_CACHE`) was introduced, but executed as normal by that version and higher.  `SQL_NO_CACHE` is used by `mysqldump` to avoid the interaction between a running backup, and the query cache.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you! That's very useful information.